# Error Main Exception

Tags: java, exception, thread-safety, program-entry-point

So i try running code that sorts an array. It keeps throwing me errors.
This is some of the code. Can you tell me why it throws errors? Thank you! By the way, the code has to be in this format. Thank you!

Every time I compile it I get Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1

I really need to understand this before my exam!

Pseudo code:

```
loop i from 1 to n-1 by ones (where n is the # of elements in the array),
        set j = i,
        set Min = array at i,
        loop while (j > 0) AND (array at j-1 > Min),
            set array at j = array at j-1,
            j = j -1,
        end while loop,
        set array at j = Min,
    end loop i,
    return the array
```

Code:

```
    int myArray[] = {1, 6, -1, 7, 83, 19, -3, 6, 2, 4, 6, 32, 66, -9};
    int n = myArray.length;
    myArray = doop(myArray);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        System.out.println(myArray[i]);
    }
}

private static int[] doop(int[] myArray) {
    int n = myArray.length;
    int swap;
    for (int i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        int j = i;
        int min = myArray[i];
        while ((j == 0) && (myArray[j - 1] <= min)) {
            myArray[j] = myArray[j - 1];
            j = j - 1;
        }
        myArray[j] = min;
    }
    return myArray;
}
```

Comment: 1. Format your question properly please: separate the pseudo-code from real Java code, 2. Which line throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException?, 3. Have you even tried to debug it or just want us to solve your problem?

Comment: I don't have much knowledge with debugging. And i am sorry, I did not notice that the pseudo code became code. I would like a short answer, I'm sure the problem isn't too big, but I have no clue what is wrong. I want to learn from the mistake, but cant find it.

Comment: When you write your question you can see how it will look like in preview section. You can also see this section while updating your post with [[edit]] option. So please use this option to improve readability of your question.

Comment: Thank you for the edit suggestion. I'm still new here.

Answer (score 2):

You're getting the exception because of this line:

```
while ((j == 0) && (myArray[j - 1] <= min)) {
```

If `j == 0` then you access the array at position `j-1` which is `-1` and therefore, as the exception tells you, out of bounds.

This condition makes no sense at all. You should revise your code and see that it makes sense to you (for example, in your psuedo-code, the condition is `j > 0`).

Comment: Ohh wow, I didn't notice that it was greater than, haha. Thank you for noticing. But once I changed that, it still does not work...

Comment: Yes, because you still don't match your pseudo code. change your entire condition to `while ((j > 0) && (myArray[j - 1] > min))` and I believe it should be fine.

Comment: I have, and I still get Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1

Comment: It works fine for me. Are you sure you've changed both parts of the condition to match the pseudo-code? If you're still getting an exception, provide more information about it (what have you changed from the original code and where is the exception thrown).

Comment: Ohh wow, I changed one letter in the first variable and it threw an error. Haha. Thank's a lot, can't believe it was something as stupid as this XD

Comment: The only issue is that when I run it, it spits out -9
-3
-1
1
6
7
83
19
2
6
4
6
32
66 Which is not in order. I'll try to figure that out myself. Thank you! I am still having this issue though. Haha.